# How to solve $x\log_2 (x) = 10^6$ using Newton's Method?

Tags: numerical-methods

I know that there are a few questions on how to solve this particular equation, but I'm not very proficient in maths and would like to follow a method which I had a little bit more of a knowledge of and it did seem simpler and best way to put my working for. I have not really studied it in length mathematically but have seen it applied in computer science.

[image: my working]

So above is my working for this method, choosing an initial value of 60,000 as that put me quite close to 0 when I used it as a value of n. My problem is is that I genuinely thought it will definitely lead to me an answer by what I read, yet I can't even get x3 without getting a maths error in my calculator.

What does this mean? Does it mean that I can't use this method to find the solution to this question from maths that I know of and I have to go into teaching myself Lambert W to solve this? Did I start with the wrong x1..? I haven't got the practice in Newton's method before so this is quite new to me.

Comment: Your title has $\log x$, but your text has $\log_2 x$. Can you resolve this please?

Comment: As for your calculator error: you are trying to compute $\log_2 C$ when $C$ is negative. But it looks to me like you have a double negative that you have forgotten to convert to a positive ($60,000-\frac{-47,639}{\cdots}$).

Comment: @TonyK Thank you I see it was a simple mistake now earlier than the bit I tried to make sure I input correctly into the calculator many times.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

As already said, you have a mistake in your calculations.

You are tryind to find the zero of function
$$f(x)=\frac{x \log (x)}{\log (2)}-10^6$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{\log (x)}{\log (2)}+\frac{1}{\log (2)}$$
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n \log (x_n)-10^6 \log (2)}{\log (x_n)+1}$$ Simplify this last expression
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+10^6 \log (2)}{\log (x_n)+1}$$ As written, less sources for mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

$$ f=  \dfrac{x \log x }{10^6 \log 2}-1$$

Find derivative and apply the procedure you have given.